# Mod_rewrite for IIS

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, iis-6

Is there anything similar to mod_rewrite for IIS 6/7? I want to be able to point several domains (I'm guessing using CNAMEs) to one domain "abc.com", and then do a redirect to "abc.com/start.html" once the browser hits that domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, [URLRewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net) is good and open source.

Answer (score 2):

The more advanced tool is ISAPI Rewrite (there is free and paid versions)

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

It allows you setting almost all kinds of rules which mod_rewrite can do.

Answer (score 2):

We use the [Ionics ISAPI Rewriter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF).  It's configuration is a subset of what is available with Apache's mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

[Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) is a product that emulates Apache behavior on IIS7.
For IIS6 ISAPI_Rewrite 3 is the tool that does the job of Apache mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite/ will work for IIS 7 (it doesn't and won't work for IIS 6). It has a Administration UI and was designed for IIS 7.