# Redirect visitors to the canonical URL for a page using IIS

Tags: iis

I want to ensure that anybody who goes to http://example.com/* gets automatically redirected to http://www.example.com/*. Currently, IIS allows either URL form to work, meaning that any page can be accessed at multiple URLs, which has a number of disadvantages (SEO, etc).

Is there any way to do this built into IIS (especially IIS 6) without setting up a third-party rewriting engine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683635/mod-rewrite-for-iis)? It seems like a bazooka to kill a mosquito.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to simply remove the DNS entries for 'www.mysite.com', so the only DNS entries that exist are for 'mysite.com'.

Alternatively, here's a couple of techiques for redirecting to a canonical URI:

- http://www.kalyani.com/2010/01/redirecting-to-canonical-url-in-iis7/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203216/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072810-1.aspx
- http://www.stevenhargrove.com/redirect-web-pages/

Basically you want to hand back a 301 Moved Permanently status for the non-canonical URIs, along with the canonical URI so the user agent may load it instead.

Comment: Well, the "easy way" harms the user experience, so that's out. Users shouldn't have to remember what to type. Besides, standard practice is to use the www subdomain as the canonical one (try going to google.com, etc.) Of the other 3 techniques: the first is perfect but is IIS7 only; the third isn't really relevant; but the middle one describes a wide variety of techniques for IIS 6 and 7. The result appears to be that for static pages (as opposed to ASP.NET pages) on IIS 6, proprietary third-party software is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I have another solution for you:

```
<rule name="Canonical domain name" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Will this work in IIS 6?  I thought general rewrite stuff didn't appear til IIS 7.