# Equivalent Url Rewrite in .NET?

Tags: .net, url, url-rewriting

I'm from a LAMP background.  I'm trying to come up with a .NET equivalent for the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

In the php world, I just put this code into a .htaccess file that sits in my web root.  Then each of the following urls `http://mysite.com/helloworld`, `http://mysite.com/helloworld.php`, and `http://mysite.com/helloworld?param=5` and `http://mysite.com/helloworld.php?param=5` resolve to the page helloworld.php, with the latter two having the $_GET['param'] populated.  How do I achieve the same results in the .Net world with aspx pages?

I am using ASP.NET web forms.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET webforms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod_rewrite for IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683635/mod-rewrite-for-iis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either download and install the UrlRewrite 2.0 HttpModule manually from www.iis.net, or use the Web Platform Installer (WPI) to install it. Personally, I prefer WPI.

Grab the WPI from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

It will let you install and configure all aspects of your Windows Web development environment.

-Oisin